# Can I modify TeXstudio to use Windows Powershell instead of CMD?

Tags: texstudio, editors

My admin and me have been unsuccessfully trying to get LaTeX running on my work computer (both portable and non-portable), but we’re both stumped. It turns out that the superadmin has a group policy that users can’t run CMD, but we can use Powershell. Running `latex.exe` in Powershell is successful (even though if I double click `latex.exe` it gives me an error of `0xc0000142`, so I assume it’s using CMD).

Therefore, is there a way for me to tell my editor, TeXstudio in this case, to use Powershell to call LaTeX instead of CMD?

I found [this](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a) on TeXstudio's manual, but unfortunately I’m not computer savvy enough to understand if what I want to do is possible.

Comment: I don't think TeXstudio calls the shell at all during builds. The manual says "All commands specified in the configuration (i.e. Commands and User Commands) are executed directly. There is no shell involved." Are you getting an error when trying to run pdflatex in TeXstudio? If so, what is it? I guess it would be telling if TXS also gave the same "0xc0000142" error message. Also, can you show us a picture of `Configure TeXstudio -> Commands` page just to be sure you are configuring TXS correctly?

Comment: Otherwise use sharelatex, aka run it in a browser

Comment: Imho texstudio is using `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` to get the console output at the bottom but it sounds rather odd if a policy would forbid this. But if this is really the case you could try  winedt instead, it has its own console.

Comment: @Troy, I was a little confused by what that meant. What made me think that it was using CMD was the mentioning of "command line tools". The Configure Texstudio -> Commands is the default, and just as it appears in the manual for "Pdflatex" (which is one of the ones that's giving me an error). The error on the TeXstudio messages is "Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "myName".tex"

I can run the same command from Powershell successfully.

Comment: @daleif, that will be my fallback... I rather keep away from browser stuff because my company has it unconventionally tight with firewalls and proxies.. making browsing slow.

Comment: @Ulrike, I agree that's odd, but not surprising since they have very silly policies here... and thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately purchasing software for my company's computer is not an option.

Comment: I didn't say you should purchase it but try it out. If it works you would know that solution is possible and can make a feature request.

Comment: @ECastro Since the "0xc0000142" error did not show up in TXS, I highly doubt TXS is running cmd at all. Can you try providing an absolute path to pdflatex instead in the settings? https://imgur.com/a/Hahja2t so you get something like `"C:/<path>/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. See if that works? Is there even a log file being produced?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, that's a good idea, I'll try that out, might help narrowing down what's actually blocking this

Comment: @Troy, I forgot to mention that sometimes when I start TeXstudio, the messagebox with the "0xc0000142" error comes up. Setting the absolute path gave me the same error unfortunately: Error: Command crashed: C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "myName".tex

Comment: @Troy, oh and no a log file is not being produced. Thanks for helping me trying to figure this thing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem not using the answer to my question, but for completeness I'll give both the answer and my solution to my problem.

**Question: How to run Powershell (PS) commands from TeXstudio?**

1) [Enable scripting in PS](https://superuser.com/questions/106360/how-to-enable-execution-of-powershell-scripts)

2) Create whatever PS script you would like to call, say latex.ps1

3) In Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Commands, precede the call to your script with "powershell", e.g., `powershell C:\PS_Scripts\latex.ps1 %.tex`

**Solution to my problem of having a "0xc0000142" error when trying to directly open latex.exe, but not when running it from a batch file or powershell**

For some reason (probably due to a group policy), I could not run latex.exe (or any of the other executables such as pdflatex.exe) and I would come up with a "0xc0000142" if I tried manually running them by double-clicking them, or the error of "Error: Command crashed: ..." in the TeXstudio messages if I ran it from TeXstudio.

My solution was to create a .bat file calling the executables, and call the .bat file in Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Commands instead of the exectuables.

Example:

"pdflatex.bat" file with contents:

```
    pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %1
```

Entry in "PdfLaTeX" in Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Commands

```
    C:\TeXstudio_bat\pdflatex.bat %.tex
```